# return google contacts api v3 photo?

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

OK I am trying to retrive a photo for each contcat using the google contacts api v3. I've managed to get the photo back but I am unable to decode whatever google is dumping at me. 
how to i convert this:

```
`����JFIF���                          !"$"$  ��``"����A"!12ABQR�#abqr�������$3C���Ss��������0 !1AQ�aq�����"2�����?�MqM!��zfe�@���I    �J�K�"�-5�ҥ�UW���8�͚��J���,��nȿ� �%�kM��D?��D��Nj6���i�>���u��D��~ �Zc4�^I�Iw��Tt��e/Tr�(��c����(`��ڪς������)|�e�NN�����G������jH�3�}�pD��U���з��Ί<) ��hW����E�G�y۵�[�i���԰s�c��q��    ��j�X�@,�N�W� ���ZE����$_ry���K:�Ư���\ʧ���Eq(z�G5��y����+\��|��] �J����(�(�e������6c�o�����ʹ�c��6qw}*,Ebrۄ��+i��܄5�T���IP"r��R*Z#�y���efJt�S���RDH���2��j*�Lͧ��R7mH�'X��,Z3�0)�p[.�W�At��h�wdl�T;)K� G*��-���k��Խ�p�ߔG�:����aى�@a�#q�����X��"�����phS.����LW(���CgE����&�<�L�N�7U���|�W�B��Ǔ6�21���DQ���I���=#F�)Pp%�5n���V�^.���ʟ��oX8-8�rIɭ'�����jMѵ��v��u5�"��"��o������F�����|���b"D7(W6��&�[K��0�ŹM,���=�-��QE�jS4MZ�2Kh��*4�� �����L��*$�v���x��K0�]���U�\I�l6�i8�c�[f���g�� اE�P�$4�F�-�>$X͇��C��v+���N�.�$6�m�X�a�3)2Y� �R�D��?R�`���e�d�f�љl����y�R(1�2�f�qٗmu�-K-���]ț�_D����WQ����S˂:�� ��w5��SC�ovT�lCK��,n��l �� ��{ �Ҏd{H�Қ~�ꋊ�*~$A"�$K�5���w��vsȪ�cfO����9���R&1���f@J�j��|�q�(l�.�ܛ��((=h�{W��~��4S�GK�!`f!�%�̯�k:'*M�$$$�"��9�]���"�������k�1����� 4B�H�.��Z ѕ<#/'e�w��T�M4m�Z�8���ʆe��~]�Vȕ�xU�\�ian$�7�L6$9Ka �G�L���$ʈk]��8�5+a~�x�QbN#�������W� :�7�����ٹ/`���-'g��e�x���]� �.����zS_���o;��}���t6�t|�aK%U�zί�4�����E(��*�Y�-ߝދ-��1I�iV��6�"��䂦I؈U�@�챥�@��-����)���5,�_�yQq �^�Ű�}�}���̵*��/4�V�����wR����G c�A��B��'2�e���Xϴ�K���YGYF�CpLI�   ImZ��������$; �؁=thy���_� �>Ø���:G.ET-�BEBQ���I~X��:dbN����E���wԠ�F��~��N��'8@���������2<��Bۛns*z���$�θ��@����*�U&Dk�� F1���7�H�L�\9I7�lU��)v�/{�E�|ͧr���*V��߽)���B'-0. ���${s\4�H���W}2�ْc��!t&��?�ޒh�����F��j�<; �E�p�jD�A�Ľ�X�p ����R�4p����@�������{n�������bc  "�M���^tD�m����t�6S�`D97��9�T mf]��{GX�ӷ��&_E�Wܗ��_>�Q5����-��D2��m�   8�d3��%�����fw�͖0-����+^Xt`1�2y�.x��[# {c�Z$��+O��@p�u�o0 +e��a�%Mٓ|t����p��j�=Z���=�1;�8,: ��o�#�ۄIsN����y�n��`tRh����q:&��a�"=�4=�����㉫۔u�R.����y�h�����n �մ�I>$Q�}������p�'�rVwVG.�$Jb@�%.����1O=��$�4,wlW[C�ޛve�2˷+"#=J'l"GT�l�;��u9�ZA�#�H*>��cy{8I�W3���'���4J�����mV��{a�NtgXc_,��N!����ѕ<#�^9�\=�'�p��+�N����]�B�7�f �ZO("Aq�a6��-�2�~�3w(9A'AEH�@���U���҇����̇o �ga�̰�8��+����tS���;}�9��J����vTi�  ��H-2QL���D�����B������pyygܹ�Yd[�Hͽ���rw�X�ehy�Zo�̾0A�SÇ��٧�f�ZdD Ƅ�:ʙ�U�$cbt��2H���3�wXj���{ ��F�����.��:�UL�k+��Q��^�&ϖ9/�t�邸��SXY��[H�w���&���?�5!�$���n�[��`�j�e0(д;Ff']���`�]�m~��dI*fj�t�z��[-0��s�=�)�]T�}�N_�����u��D��~ �Zc4�^I�Iw��Tt��e/Tr�(��c����(`��ڪς������)|�e�NN�����G������jH�3�}�pD��U���з��Ί<) ��hW����E�G�y۵�[�i���԰s�c��q��  ��j�X�@,�N�W� ���ZE����$_ry���K:�Ư���\ʧ���Eq(z�G5��y����+\��|��] �J����(�(�e������6c�o�����ʹ�c��6qw}*,Ebrۄ��+i��܄5�T���IP"r��R*Z#�y���efJt�S���RDH���2��j*�Lͧ��R7mH�'X��,Z3�0)�p[.�W�At��h�wdl�T;)K� G*��-���k��Խ�p�ߔG�:����aى�@a�#q�����X��"�����phS.����LW(���CgE����&�<�L�N�7U���|�W�B��Ǔ6�21���DQ���I���=#F�)Pp%�5n���V�^.���ʟ��oX8-8�rIɭ'�����jMѵ��v��u5�"��"��o������F�����|���b"D7(W6��&�[K��0�ŹM,���=�-��QE�jS4MZ�2Kh��*4�� �����L��*$�v���x��K0�]���U�\I�l6�i8�c�[f���g�� اE�P�$4�F�-�>$X͇��C��v+���N�.�$6�m�X�a�3)2Y� �R�D��?R�`���e�d�f�љl����y�R(1�2�f�qٗmu�-K-���]ț�_D����WQ����S˂:�� ��w5��SC�ovT�lCK��,n��l �� ��{ �Ҏd{H�Қ~�ꋊ�*~$A"�$K�5���w��vsȪ�cfO����9���R&1���f@J�j��|�q�(l�.�ܛ��((=h�{W��~��4S�GK�!`f!�%�̯�k:'*M�$$$�"��9�]���"�������k�1����� 4B�H�.��Z ѕ<#/'e�w��T�M4m�Z�8���ʆe��~]�Vȕ�xU�\�ian$�7�L6$9Ka �G�L���$ʈk]��8�5+a~�x�QbN#�������W� :�7�����ٹ/`���-'g��e�x���]� �.����zS_���o;��}���t6�t|�aK%U�zί�4�����E(��*�Y�-ߝދ-��1I�iV��6�"��䂦I؈U�@�챥�@��-����)���5,�_�yQq �^�Ű�}�}���̵*��/4�V�����wR����G c�A��B��'2�e���Xϴ�K���YGYF�CpLI�   ImZ��������$; �؁=thy���_� �>Ø���:G.ET-�BEBQ���I~X��:dbN����E���wԠ�F��~��N��'8@���������2<��Bۛns*z���$�θ��@����*�U&Dk�� F1���7�H�L�\9I7�lU��)v�/{�E�|ͧr���*V��߽)���B'-0. ���${s\4�H���W}2�ْc��!t&��?�ޒh�����F��j�<; �E�p�jD�A�Ľ�X�p ����R�4p����@�������{n�������bc  "�M���^tD�m����t�6S�`D97��9�T mf]��{GX�ӷ��&_E�Wܗ��_>�Q5����-��D2��m�   8�d3��%�����fw�͖0-����+^Xt`1�2y�.x��[# {c�Z$��+O��@p�u�o0 +e��a�%Mٓ|t����p��j�=Z���=�1;�8,: ��o�#�ۄIsN����y�n��`tRh����q:&��a�"=�4=�����㉫۔u�R.����y�h�����n �մ�I>$Q�}������p�'�rVwVG.�$Jb@�%.����1O=��$�4,wlW[C�ޛve�2˷+"#=J'l"GT�l�;��u9�ZA�#�H*>��cy{8I�W3���'���4J�����mV��{a�NtgXc_,��N!����ѕ<#�^9�\=�'�p��+�N����]�B�7�f �ZO("Aq�a6��-�2�~�3w(9A'AEH�@���U���҇����̇o �ga�̰�8��+����tS���;}�9��J����vTi�  ��H-2QL���D�����B������pyygܹ�Yd[�Hͽ���rw�X�ehy�Zo�̾0A�SÇ��٧�f�ZdD Ƅ�:ʙ�U�$cbt��2H���3�wXj���{ ��F�����.��:�UL�k+��Q��^�&ϖ9/�t�邸��SXY��[H�w���&���?�5!�`$���n�[��`�j�e0(д;Ff']���`�]�m~��dI*fj�t�z��[-0��s�=�)�]T�}�N_��
```

into an actual image file: 
heres the php I'm using to retrive it:

```
 $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
 $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');    
 $output_array = array();
  foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    // Initialize an array out here.
    $entry_array = array();

    // Get the title and link attributes (link as an array)
    $entry_array['title'] = (string)$entry->title;

    $entry_array['hrefs'] = array();
    foreach($entry->link as $link) {
      // append each href in a loop
      $entry_array['hrefs'][] = $link->attributes()->href;
    }

    // If there are never more than 1 email, you don't need a loop here.
    foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email) {
      // Get the email
      $entry_array['email'] = (string)$email->attributes()->address;
    }
    // Append your array to the larger output
    $output_array[] = $entry_array;
  }
foreach($output_array as $key=>$value){

  if (isset($value['email'], $value['title'])) {
    # code...
    echo $value['email'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['title'].'<br/>'; 
          $photo = new Google_HttpRequest($value['hrefs'][0][0]);
          $photo_val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($photo);
      $photo_return = $photo_val->getResponseBody();


      echo $photo_return;
      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $photo_return . '" />';
      echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($photo_val);
    echo "</pre>";     
    //echo '<img src="'.$value['hrefs'][0][0].'.jpeg" /><br/>';
  }
}
```

heres the full output withoput grabbing the response body:

```
    object(Google_HttpRequest)#187 (10) {
  ["batchHeaders":"Google_HttpRequest":private]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    string(16) "application/http"
    ["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]=>
    string(6) "binary"
    ["MIME-Version"]=>
    string(3) "1.0"
    ["Content-Length"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["url":protected]=>
  string(153) "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/******%40gmail.com/184afeb8c9eab50/5cGWlggt7qNR0AOdAsvgDQ?key=************"
  ["requestMethod":protected]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["requestHeaders":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["authorization"]=>
    string(88) "Bearer ya29.1.*************"
  }
  ["postBody":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["userAgent":protected]=>
  string(43) "LYST-it sharing google-api-php-client/0.6.5"
  ["responseHttpCode":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["responseHeaders":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["content-type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["expires"]=>
    string(29) "Tue, 21 Jan 2014 13:27:35 GMT"
    ["date"]=>
    string(29) "Tue, 21 Jan 2014 13:27:35 GMT"
    ["cache-control"]=>
    string(49) "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform"
    ["vary"]=>
    string(44) "Accept, X-GData-Authorization, GData-Version"
    ["gdata-version"]=>
    string(3) "1.0"
    ["transfer-encoding"]=>
    string(7) "chunked"
    ["x-content-type-options"]=>
    string(7) "nosniff"
    ["x-frame-options"]=>
    string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
    ["x-xss-protection"]=>
    string(13) "1; mode=block"
    ["server"]=>
    string(3) "GSE"
    ["alternate-protocol"]=>
    string(8) "443:quic"
  }
  ["responseBody":protected]=>
  string(3033) "����JFIF���                               !"$"$     ��``"����A"!12ABQR�#abqr�������$3C���Ss��������0    !1AQ�aq�����"2�����?�MqM!��zfe�@���I  �J�K�"�-5�ҥ�UW���8�͚��J���,��nȿ�
�%�kM��D?��D��Nj6���i�>���u��D��~
�Zc4�^I�Iw��Tt��e/Tr�(��c����(`��ڪς������)|�e�NN�����G������jH�3�}�pD��U���з��Ί<)
��hW����E�G�y۵�[�i���԰s�c��q��   ��j�X�@,�N�W�
���ZE����$_ry���K:�Ư���\ʧ���Eq(z�G5��y����+\��|��]
�J����(�(�e������6c�o�����ʹ�c��6qw}*,Ebrۄ��+i��܄5�T���IP"r��R*Z#�y���efJt�S���RDH���2��j*�Lͧ��R7mH�'X��,Z3�0)�p[.�W�At��h�wdl�T;)K� G*��-���k��Խ�p�ߔG�:����aى�@a�#q�����X��"�����phS.����LW(���CgE����&�<�L�N�7U���|�W�B��Ǔ6�21���DQ���I���=#F�)Pp%�5n���V�^.���ʟ��oX8-8�rIɭ'�����jMѵ��v��u5�"��"��o������F�����|���b"D7(W6��&�[K��0�ŹM,���=�-��QE�jS4MZ�2Kh��*4��
�����L��*$�v���x��K0�]���U�\I�l6�i8�c�[f���g��
اE�P�$4�F�-�>$X͇��C��v+���N�.�$6�m�X�a�3)2Y�
�R�D��?R�`���e�d�f�љl����y�R(1�2�f�qٗmu�-K-���]ț�_D����WQ����S˂:�� ��w5��SC�ovT�lCK��,n��l
��
��{
�Ҏd{H�Қ~�ꋊ�*~$A"�$K�5���w��vsȪ�cfO����9���R&1���f@J�j��|�q�(l�.�ܛ��((=h�{W��~��4S�GK�!`f!�%�̯�k:'*M�$$$�"��9�]���"�������k�1�����
4B�H�.��Z ѕ<#/'e�w��T�M4m�Z�8���ʆe��~]�Vȕ�xU�\�ian$�7�L6$9Ka
�G�L���$ʈk]��8�5+a~�x�QbN#�������W�
:�7�����ٹ/`���-'g��e�x���]� �.����zS_���o;��}���t6�t|�aK%U�zί�4�����E(��*�Y�-ߝދ-��1I�iV��6�"��䂦I؈U�@�챥�@��-����)���5,�_�yQq
�^�Ű�}�}���̵*��/4�V�����wR����G
c�A��B��'2�e���Xϴ�K���YGYF�CpLI�  ImZ��������$;
�؁=thy���_� �>Ø���:G.ET-�BEBQ���I~X��:dbN����E���wԠ�F��~��N��'8@���������2<��Bۛns*z���$�θ��@����*�U&Dk��
F1���7�H�L�\9I7�lU��)v�/{�E�|ͧr���*V��߽)���B'-0.
���${s\4�H���W}2�ْc��!t&��?�ޒh�����F��j�<;
�E�p�jD�A�Ľ�X�p
����R�4p����@�������{n�������bc   "�M���^tD�m����t�6S�`D97��9�T
mf]��{GX�ӷ��&_E�Wܗ��_>�Q5����-��D2��m�   8�d3��%�����fw�͖0-����+^Xt`1�2y�.x��[#
{c�Z$��+O��@p�u�o0
+e��a�%Mٓ|t����p��j�=Z���=�1;�8,:
��o�#�ۄIsN����y�n��`tRh����q:&��a�"=�4=�����㉫۔u�R.����y�h�����n
�մ�I>$Q�}������p�'�rVwVG.�$Jb@�%.����1O=��$�4,wlW[C�ޛve�2˷+"#=J'l"GT�l�;��u9�ZA�#�H*>��cy{8I�W3���'���4J�����mV��{a�NtgXc_,��N!����ѕ<#�^9�\=�'�p��+�N����]�B�7�f
�ZO("Aq�a6��-�2�~�3w(9A'AEH�@���U���҇����̇o
�ga�̰�8��+����tS���;}�9��J����vTi�   ��H-2QL���D�����B������pyygܹ�Yd[�Hͽ���rw�X�ehy�Zo�̾0A�SÇ��٧�f�ZdD
Ƅ�:ʙ�U�$cbt��2H���3�wXj���{
��F�����.��:�UL�k+��Q��^�&ϖ9/�t�邸��SXY��[H�w���&���?�5!�$���n�[��`�j�e0(д;Ff']���`�]�m~��dI*fj�t�z��[-0��s�=�)�]T�}�N_��"
  ["accessKey"]=>
  NULL
}
```

How do i decode that big chunk of nonsensical data into and image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it the trick here is to base64 encode prior to dumping the data like so:

```
  $imgData = base64_encode($photo_return);
  echo "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' />";
```