# Google contacts API Broken link when trying to retrieve contacts photo from json response

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to retrieve my Google contacts photos using a JSON response. I figured out how to authenticate and how to retrieve the info that i need.

Now, i'm trying to display the contacts photo as well, and i know that the photo is located in this bit of the json response:

```
[link] => Array
   (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
          [type] => image/*
          [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/mymail%40gmail.com/{code}
          [gd$etag] => "{code}"
         )
   )
```

Now, if I echo the href, and then add the access_token, the link looks like this ->

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{{my-email-address}}/7473ab09b97a34?v=3.0?access_token={{my-access-token}}
```

And this results in a broken link.
I've noticed tho that if i remove the `?ver=3`, the link actually works.
Problem is: the ?ver=3 comes from the json response so i don't know how to remove it.

Now, i've tried to set the link as a variable, to remove the `?ver=3`, bur the links is still broken as i don't know where to find the `{code}` needed for each contacts.

Any help? how can i solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259748/return-google-contacts-api-v3-photo.

Comment: You could just created an image based on the url, by encoding the response into a base64 encode to display the image.

Comment: @Rivero do you mind provide me an example? Or some reference? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the related question mentioned before ([return google contacts api v3 photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259748/return-google-contacts-api-v3-photo)), perhaps deal with the JSON response like this:

```
foreach($output_array as $key=>$value){
    if (isset($value['email'], $value['title'])) {
        echo $value['email'].'<br/>';
        echo $value['title'].'<br/>'; 
        $photo = new Google_HttpRequest($value['hrefs'][0][0]);
        $photo_val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($photo);
        $photo_return = $photo_val->getResponseBody();
        $imgData = base64_encode($photo_return);
        echo "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' />";
    }
}
```